# Is there a way to use IFS to read delimited strings in a loop?

Tags: bash, ifs

Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  IFS=';' read -r
  echo "Read: $REPLY"
done
```

If I run this script and type in `1;2;3`, I expect and desire to see the output:

```
Read: 1
Read: 2
Read: 3
```

However, the output I get is

```
Read: 1;2;3
```

It seems like IFS is being ignored.

**What is happening here, and is it possible to get the desired output?**

Note that I am already aware of the array option (`read -a` and then loop through the array), and I am specifically interested in the single read case.

Comment: You can't read a non newline delimited string like `1;2;3` using a read command in a loop. Either read the whole string first, split  and then loop later

Comment: Ah I guess I'm misunderstanding the man page for `read` in that case. :(

Comment: you can do `while true; do read -d';' -r ; echo "Read: $REPLY"; done`, but that delimits the input on `;` and spits out the read character till the delimit character.

Comment: You're confusing the *field* separator (controlled by `IFS`) with the *line* delimiter (normally newline, changeable with the `-d` option). `read` reads one line at a time, not one field at a time.

Comment: @merlin2011, do you know in advance how many fields there are?

Comment: I do not know in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` reads one line at a time. The value of `IFS` controls *word splitting*, so that if you wrote

```
IFS=';' read -r a b c
```

then your line would be split on `;` into at most 3 fields. You could then print each field separately.

```
IFS=';' read -r a b c <<< "1;2;3"
echo "Read: $a"
echo "Read: $b"
echo "Read: $c"
```

If you don't know how many fields there will be, you can populate an *array* by splitting as many times as possible and collecting the results. You can then iterate over *the array*.

```
IFS=';' read -ra arr <<< "1;2;3"
for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "Read: $x"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will always have the same number (3 in this case) of delimited fields:

```
while true
do
    IFS=';' read -r -p "enter string: " a b c

    echo "#############"

    echo "Read: ${a}"
    echo "Read: ${b}"
    echo "Read: ${c}"

    echo "#############"
done
```

**NOTE:** if there are more than 3 delimited fields `c` will be populated with fields 3-n with the delimiter included between the fields

Taking for a test drive:

```
enter string: 1;2;3
#############
Read: 1
Read: 2
Read: 3
#############
enter string: 1;2;3;4
#############
Read: 1
Read: 2
Read: 3;4                             # 3rd/4th fields stored in c
#############
enter string: a b c;d e f;g h i
#############
Read: a b c
Read: d e f
Read: g h i
#############
enter string:
```

---

If you don't know in advance the number of fields we can modify the `read` to parse and store the fields into an array then loop over the array:

```
while true
do
    IFS=';' read -r -p "enter string: " -a arr        # split input on delimiter ; and place results in array arr[]
#   typeset -p arr                                    # uncomment to display the contents of the array

    echo "#############"

    for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++))
    do
        echo "Read: ${arr[i]}"
    done

    echo "#############"
done
```

Taking for a test drive (with the `typeset -p` uncommented):

```
enter string: 1;2;3
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3")
#############
Read: 1
Read: 2
Read: 3
#############
enter string: 1;2;3;4
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4")
#############
Read: 1
Read: 2
Read: 3
Read: 4                               # 4th field stored in a separate array location
#############
enter string: a b c;d e f;g h i
declare -a arr=([0]="a b c" [1]="d e f" [2]="g h i")
#############
Read: a b c
Read: d e f
Read: g h i
#############
enter string:
```